# Sending node object to a class inside the node

Tags: node, rclcpp

I have a class named UarmControl that inherits the Node class. Inside my UarmControl class, I want to send the node it self to another class named Uarm that I want to create inside my constructor. The constructor of the Uarm class looks like this:

```
Uarm::Uarm(rclcpp::Node::SharedPtr& node, std::string &robot_ip)
```

Why is it not working to just put "this" as shown below?

```
class UarmControl : public rclcpp::Node
{
  public:
    UarmControl() : Node("uarm_control")
    {
        timer_ = this->create_wall_timer(
        10ms, std::bind(&UarmControl::timer_callback, this));

    std::string robot_ip = "192.168.8.167";
    Uarm uarm(this, robot_ip);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
This is the error I'm getting:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘Uarm::Uarm(UarmControl*, std::string&)’
   34 |     Uarm uarm(this, robot_ip);

note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘UarmControl*’ to ‘rclcpp::Node::SharedPtr&’ {aka ‘std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::Node>&’}
    6 |     Uarm(rclcpp::Node::SharedPtr& node, std::string &robot_ip);
```

So it seems that "this" does not refer to the node. I thought it would work because I read this on the ROS2 Humble MinimalPublisher C++ example page:
[image]

My goal is to replace the following code, so that the Uarm object is created within the node class. In this way I can access the Uarm functions inside my node...

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
  std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::Node> node = std::make_shared<UarmControl>();
  std::string robot_ip = "192.168.8.167";
  Uarm uarm(node, robot_ip);
  while(1)
  {
  rclcpp::spin_some(node);
  uarm.set_joint_vel(q_dot);
  }
  rclcpp::shutdown();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you share the error message and explain what you mean by 'not working'?

Comment: did you really mean to say `parsing`?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Tried to make the post a bit clearer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the answer [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/330920/ros-2-composable-node-pass-nodehandler/) (rizkymille's answer):

> You need to get the node pointer and pass it to another class. But if you do this in the class constructor, a bad_weak_ptr error will always show up. You can prevent this by initiating the class in callback.
>
> I'm gonna use ClassA and ClassB example above, say you want to extend the node to ClassB to use ClassB functions from ClassA. Here's the header code of ClassB:
>
> ```
> class ClassB {
> public:
>    ClassB(rclcpp::Node::SharedPtr node); // constructor
>
>    // your code here
>
>  private:
>    rclcpp::Node::SharedPtr node_;
>
>    // your code here
> ```
>
> and here's the definition code of ClassB:
>
> ```
> // constructor
> ClassB::ClassB(rclcpp::Node::SharedPtr node) : node_(node) {
>
>    // your code here
> }
> ```
>
> Then in ClassA file:
>
> ```
> class ClassA : public rclcpp::Node {
>   public:
>     ClassA() : Node("class_a") {
>
>       // your code here
>
>       // use one-time timer to initiate class B 
>       timer = this->create_wall_timer(500ms, std::bind(&ClassA::initialization, this));
>     }
>
>   private:
>
>     rclcpp::TimerBase::SharedPtr timer;
>
>     std::shared_ptr<ClassB> class_b;
>
>     void initialization() {
>       // get node pointer, pass into Class B
>       class_b = std::make_shared<ClassB>(shared_from_this());
>
>       // replace timer with loop callback after initialization finished
>       timer = this->create_wall_timer(500ms, std::bind(&UsingLibCpp::timer_callback, this)); 
>     }
>
>     void timer_callback() {
>       // your code here
>
>       // use Class B function
>       class_b->class_b_function();
>     }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you pass the instance of a node you do it for specific reasons. If this is the case you can pass the specific node interface, you can define the constructor in a similar way:

```
void Uarm(                        rclcpp::node_interfaces::NodeBaseInterface::SharedPtr node_base,
rclcpp::node_interfaces::NodeClockInterface::SharedPtr node_clock,
rclcpp::node_interfaces::NodeGraphInterface::SharedPtr node_graph,
rclcpp::node_interfaces::NodeLoggingInterface::SharedPtr node_logging,
rclcpp::node_interfaces::NodeParametersInterface::SharedPtr node_parameters,
rclcpp::node_interfaces::NodeServicesInterface::SharedPtr node_services,
rclcpp::node_interfaces::NodeTimersInterface::SharedPtr node_timers,
rclcpp::node_interfaces::NodeTimeSourceInterface::SharedPtr node_time_source,
rclcpp::node_interfaces::NodeTopicsInterface::SharedPtr node_topics,
rclcpp::node_interfaces::NodeWaitablesInterface::SharedPtr node_waitables)
```

This interfaces can be retrieved with the methods:

```
this->get_node_base_interface(),
this->get_node_clock_interface(),
this->get_node_graph_interface(),
this->get_node_logging_interface(),
this->get_node_parameters_interface(),
this->get_node_services_interface(),
this->get_node_timers_interface(),
this->get_node_time_source_interface(),
this->get_node_topics_interface(),
 this->get_node_waitables_interface()
```

In this way you can pass only the instances you really need

Comment: Ok, but how should I pass that in the UarmControl class?

Comment: In the constructor of the class, I wrote you the declaration